# Error when using the ruby google-cloud-automl predict method: Unknown field name in initialization map entry

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-automl

I am trying to make a single prediction request using the `google-cloud-automl` gem in the `google-cloud-ruby` library:

```
Google::Cloud::AutoML.configure do |config|
  config.credentials = "/path/to/credentials.json"
end

client = Google::Cloud::AutoML.prediction_service

payload = {
  instances: [
    { text: "example text to be classified" }
  ]
}

client.predict(name: "model_name", payload: payload)
```

The model being called is a simple binary classifier to classify a string of text. The `text` attribute is the only feature for this model.

When calling `.predict`, I am getting the following error:

`Unknown field name 'instances' in initialization map entry`

Has anyone else run into this before? I can't seem to find any examples of what the `payload` hash should look like.

Comment: did you find any solution? I have same problem

Comment: hello from one year in the future. same problem. no solution.